# Count max words in sentence from given string in Go

Tags: algorithm, go, optimization, review

i'm new in Go... and i'm looking for new ways to optimize and/or fix this algorithm to count max words in sentence from given string. Sentence is ending with '?' or '!' or '.' and function should return int >= 0.

```
// MaxWordsInSentences - return max words in one sentences
func MaxWordsInSentences(S string) (result int) {


    r, _ := regexp.Compile("[.||?||!]")
    count := strings.Count(S, ".") + strings.Count(S, "!") + strings.Count(S, "?") // Total sentaces

    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        sentence := r.Split(S, count)[i]
        splitSentence := strings.Split(sentence, " ")

        var R []string
        for _, str := range splitSentence {
            if str != "" {
                R = append(R, str)
            }
        }

        if len(R) > result {
            result = len(R)
        }
    }

    return

}
```

Example

Sentence => `"One two three four five six seven eight. One two? One two three four five six seven eight nine? One two three! One two three four."`

Should return 9 as result

Comment: What does "count max words" mean?

Comment: What is the regex `"[.||?||!]"`? It looks like you just wanted `[.?!]`

Comment: @EliBendersky - task is to count words sentence, it should return the highest number of words in one sentance. Input is string with N sentances ending with . or ? or !

Comment: @JimB i found that in other similar task, basically translation is to match:  ! OR ? OR .

Comment: The OR operator is just `|`, but that's a character class which itself is a logical OR, so you don't need it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the trivial test case you provided, your algorithm appears to work. Your algorithm doesn't work very well on real text.

---

Consider my simple algorithm:

```
func maxSentenceWords(s string) int {
    maxWords, nWords := 0, 0
    inWord := false
    for _, r := range s {
        switch r {
        case '.', '?', '!':
            inWord = false
            if maxWords < nWords {
                maxWords = nWords
            }
            nWords = 0
        default:
            if unicode.IsSpace(r) {
                inWord = false
            } else if inWord == false {
                inWord = true
                nWords++
            }
        }
        if maxWords < nWords {
            maxWords = nWords
        }
    }
    return maxWords
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/OD8jNW1hyAa

It passes your simple test. A short benchmark (Lorem Ipsum) runs very quickly and a long benchmark (Shakespeare) runs quickly

```
$ go test words_test.go -run=PeterSO -v -bench=PeterSO -benchmem -timeout=5m
=== RUN   TestPeterSO
--- PASS: TestPeterSO (0.00s)
BenchmarkPeterSOL-4    300000        4027 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkPeterSOS-4        20    54084832 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
$
```

---

Consider your complex algorithm:

```
func MaxWordsInSentences(S string) (result int) {
    r, _ := regexp.Compile("[.||?||!]")
    count := strings.Count(S, ".") + strings.Count(S, "!") + strings.Count(S, "?") // Total sentaces

    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        sentence := r.Split(S, count)[i]
        splitSentence := strings.Split(sentence, " ")

        var R []string
        for _, str := range splitSentence {
            if str != "" {
                R = append(R, str)
            }
        }

        if len(R) > result {
            result = len(R)
        }
    }

    return
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/MCj-XxEid73

It passes your simple test. A short benchmark (Lorem Ipsum) runs slowly and a long benchmark (Shakespeare) runs a very long time (killed after 5 minutes).

```
$ go test words_test.go -run=Ljubon -v -bench=Ljubon -benchmem -timeout=5m
=== RUN   TestLjubon
--- PASS: TestLjubon (0.00s)
BenchmarkLjubonL-4    20000    78623 ns/op    6984 B/op   62 allocs/op
*** Test killed with quit: ran too long (6m0s).
$
```

---

`test words_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
    "testing"
    "unicode"
)

var sentences = "One two three four five six seven eight. One two? One two three four five six seven eight nine? One two three! One two three four."

var loremipsum = `
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
`

var shakespeare = func() string {
    // The Complete Works of William Shakespeare by William Shakespeare
    // http://www.gutenberg.org/files/100/100-0.txt
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(`/home/peter/shakespeare.100-0.txt`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return string(data)
}()

func maxSentenceWords(s string) int {
    maxWords, nWords := 0, 0
    inWord := false
    for _, r := range s {
        switch r {
        case '.', '?', '!':
            inWord = false
            if maxWords < nWords {
                maxWords = nWords
            }
            nWords = 0
        default:
            if unicode.IsSpace(r) {
                inWord = false
            } else if inWord == false {
                inWord = true
                nWords++
            }
        }
        if maxWords < nWords {
            maxWords = nWords
        }
    }
    return maxWords
}

func TestPeterSO(t *testing.T) {
    want := 9
    got := maxSentenceWords(sentences)
    if got != want {
        t.Errorf("want %d; got %d", want, got)
    }
}

func BenchmarkPeterSOL(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        maxSentenceWords(loremipsum)
    }
}

func BenchmarkPeterSOS(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        maxSentenceWords(shakespeare)
    }
}

// MaxWordsInSentences - return max words in one sentences
func MaxWordsInSentences(S string) (result int) {
    r, _ := regexp.Compile("[.||?||!]")
    count := strings.Count(S, ".") + strings.Count(S, "!") + strings.Count(S, "?") // Total sentaces

    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        sentence := r.Split(S, count)[i]
        splitSentence := strings.Split(sentence, " ")

        var R []string
        for _, str := range splitSentence {
            if str != "" {
                R = append(R, str)
            }
        }

        if len(R) > result {
            result = len(R)
        }
    }

    return
}

func TestLjubon(t *testing.T) {
    want := 9
    got := MaxWordsInSentences(sentences)
    if got != want {
        t.Errorf("want %d; got %d", want, got)
    }
}

func BenchmarkLjubonL(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        MaxWordsInSentences(loremipsum)
    }
}

func BenchmarkLjubonS(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        MaxWordsInSentences(shakespeare)
    }
}

func main() {
    s := "One two three four five six seven eight. One two? One two three four five six seven eight nine? One two three! One two three four."
    max := maxSentenceWords(s) // 9
    fmt.Println(max)
    s = "One two three! One two three four"
    max = maxSentenceWords(s) // 4
    fmt.Println(max)
    s = loremipsum
    max = maxSentenceWords(s)
    fmt.Println(max)
}
```

---

> I call it the law of the instrument, and it may be formulated as
>   follows: Give a small boy a hammer, and he will find that everything
>   he encounters needs pounding.
>
> Abraham Kaplan, The Conduct of Inquiry: Methodology for Behavioral
>   Science, 1964, page 28.

---

Is the Go `regexp` package your hammer to pound any and all text?

Comment: thnks for clarification!
As i said, i'm new in go and programming at all....so i wasn't thinking about unicode and solving in this way.
Once again, thank you for sharing this with me...

Comment: "Considder my simple algorithm" which is actually *my* algorithm posted earlier. I guess you took the effort to downvote as well? LOL

Comment: @PascaldeKloe:  Your algorithm does not even compile and it has bugs. My algorithm certainly did not come from you.

Answer (score -1):

```
func MaxWordsInSentences(s string) (result int) {
    var offset, wordCount int
    for i, r := range s {
        switch r {
        default:
            if unicode.IsSpace(r) {
                wordCount++
            }

        case '.', '?', '!':
            if wordCount > result {
                result = wordCount
            }

            wordCount = 1
        }
    }

    return
}
```

Comment: Does not compile and has bugs.